# How can I get the .avi file to work correctly after adding audio to it?

Tags: python, opencv, moviepy

Using cv2, I make a bunch of jpgs out of an mp4 file:

```
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(inp_file)
    success,image = vidcap.read()
```

```
cv2.imwrite("raw_frames/frame%d.jpg"%count,image)
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    count+=1
```

I then do a bunch of operations on all those jpgs and store them in another folder. Then I go through all of those and create an avi out of them:

```
img = Image.open(file)
width,height = img.size
frameSize = (width,height)
outfile = inp_file.split(".")[0] + '_asc'
out = cv2.VideoWriter(outfile+'.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'),ffps,frameSize)
path = "rendered_frames"
```

```
for img_i in range(len(all_images)):
    img = cv2.imread(path+"/rf_"+str(img_i)+".jpg")
    out.write(img)
print("\tVideo complete!")
out.release()
```

Then I take that video and try to add the audio from the original mp4 file back to it, using moviepy:

```
def combine_audio(vidname,audname,outname,fps):
    from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
    from moviepy.audio.io.AudioFileClip import AudioFileClip
    my_clip = VideoFileClip(vidname)
    audio_background = AudioFileClip(audname)
    final_clip = my_clip.set_audio(audio_background)
    final_clip.write_videofile(outname,fps=fps,codec='rawvideo')

combine_audio(outfile+'.avi',inp_file,outfile+"ii.avi",ffps)
```

However, there seems to be a problem with the codec. Under the current conditions, their skin turns purple, purple things turn red, white things stay pretty white etc..

Note that this happens when I add the audio back to them. Before adding audio to the video from cv2, it is perfect.

Here is a reference for what is happening now

Original:
[image: Original]

After rendering:
[image: After render]

I've tried some other values in cv2 and moviepy but no success.

I tried creating an mp4 instead with MP4V instead of DIVX with `cv2.VideoWriter()` and some mp4 codec in the audio function, but there is way too much compression for how detailed the video needs to be for what I am doing.

From moviepy's documentation it says that you could leave the codec field blank for an .avi but that causes an error.

Some additional information:
After making the video with cv with fourcc 'DIVX' (pre audio) VLC media player says the codec of the video is MPEG-4 (FMP4).
When passing 'FMP4' as the codec for moviepy, it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Your color channels are reversed, try converting from BGR to RGB before writing each video frame.